Why my music using Web Audio API sounds weaker?
Only on mobile chrome, the speaker is set to phone call during playing a music. I figured out this is because of gainNode. But gainNode is important for looping without gap and etc. I don't want to remove it. Is there any other way to fix this?
More specifically, I think the problem is
.connect(audioCtx.destination)

this part itself. I think the audio destination(speaker) is set weirdly somehow, but I have no idea how to fix this.


let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
let playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');

let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let track = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
let gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

track.connect(gainNode).connect(audioCtx.destination);

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    audio.play();
}, false);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <audio src="./src/audio/music.wav" style="display: none" controls></audio>
        <button class="play-btn" type="button">play</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




What does your gain node have to do with looping without a gap?  And, why not just set your gain node to 1.0?

I'm not sure but to loop audio without a gap, you need to use Web Audio API, and gain node seems to be important for that job. I simplified the whole code as shown. Line 4-8 of the javascript makes the problem. Without them, no speaker problem, but I cannot loop without a gap as well.

I guess that makes sense.  The MediaElementSourceNode might not produce any samples if it's actively seeking and buffered.  Though I'm kinda surprised it doesn't produce null samples like it does normally.  Honestly, this behavior is probably a bit of a glitch.  I wouldn't rely on it.  If you do have something you need to loop, you can do that reliably with the Web Audio API, either through a ScriptProcessorNode/AudioWorklet, or through the BufferSourceNode.  Anyway, you can connect your MediaElementSource directly to the context destination... no gain needed.

There is no way to do looping without a gap if I use other than Web Audio API. The methods you mentioned also includes audioCtx.destination, and without destination, any music cannot be played in Web Audio API. So I need to solve the destination problem because I need to use Web Audio API.

... all the methods I've mentioned use the Web Audio API... I suggest you read the documentation.

I mean the problem is audioCtx.destination and if I cannot fix this, then there is no reason to use Web Audio API because good sound quality comes first and looping is second.
